# Changing filename of the file when uploaded to the server

Tags: php

Is it necessary to change the filename of the file when it is uploaded to the server? Like you generate new filename before storing the file to the server.

Comment: What server-storing code are you currently using?

Comment: no it is not necessary

Comment: In general. Like what i noticed when i upload a picture from facebook and download it. then i noticed that the filename was changed when i downloaded the image.

Comment: Although it is not necessary it can help in case you try and upload several files with the same name. BUT if you store the name of the original file in an *image record* then this can be transparent to the user as the image appears to have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $newfilename);
```

Comment: Please just don't write the codes. Try to explain how this would work.

Comment: The question is not how to change the name, but is it necessary.

Comment: really very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
$temp = explode(".", $image_name);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
$target = 'location/'.$newfilename;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);
```